# ServiceWorker giving error on registration

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm doing my first PWA trying to follow some tutorials and after installing workbox and created the file sw.js I tried to register with the following code:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function (registration) {
                // Registration was successful
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            }, function (err) {
                // registration failed :(
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
            });
        });
    }
```

But, when I open the file on the web I get the following error:

error displayed on chrome console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bznd.png

If I open the directly the link on the browser I can see the sw.js file:
[sw.js file open directly on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEiAc.png)

I'm using live-server extension from Visual studio code to open it.

Comment: "When you open the file on the web", what do you mean? Opening `sw.js` directly? That "error" isn't an error, also, please post as text not images.

Comment: I mean when I go to localhost/App/sw.js I already updated the image.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that your service worker script isn't deployed at `http://127.0.0.1:5500/sw.js`. It seems like you might be serving it from `http://127.0.0.1:5500/App/sw.js` instead?

Due to the way [service worker scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#enter_service_workers) work, it's recommended that you service your service worker script from the top level of your web server, so you should move your `sw.js` file to your web root and try again.